# Can I pass custom command with arguments with Run process in Robot Framework?

Tags: process, robotframework

I have a custom command that starts up a batch process/background process and I wanted to wait until the process completed to proceed to my next step in the test. So I was trying with 'Run process'  from Process library so it will wait for the completion instead of using the 'execute command'.  However I am getting below error with 'Run process' method.

> FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file
>   specified

Below is the code used :

```
*** Settings ***
Library     Process
Library     SSHLibrary
Library     OperatingSystem

*** Test Cases ***
Example                                                                                
Open Connection     ${host}
Login               ${huser}        ${hpwd}                        
${Command} =    set variable    cash start -f program_name -args "'-arg1' -t 10 -p 3 -r 5"                                                           
${handle} =    Start Process    ${command}
```

Comment: robot doesn't care whether the command is custom or not. It simply needs to be able to find the command you want to run (ie: it needs to be on your PATH)

Comment: I rather used 'Run command'  keyword and to wait until process completion, in a for loop ,  I poll against the log file for job completion message at given interval.

Comment: For some reason 'start process'  didn't like the command that I passed, when I simply replace 'start process' with 'start command'  in above test code I provided, it worked perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

Process library keywords are executed on the server where robot test case is running and not on the server which you are trying to ssh. Hence it is not able to find the program on the server from which robot test case is being executed. "Start command" executes the program on the logged server

Answer (score 0):

According to http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html there are two approaches to passing the command. The first option is to pass "the command to execute and all arguments passed to the command as separate arguments". For example, let's suppose the command you want to execute on the command line is `python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"`. Then separating the CL elements works:

```
${handle}=   Start Process   python3   -c   "import sys; print(sys.version)"
```

Alternatively, when using shell=True "it is possible to give the whole command to execute as a single string":

```
    ${cmd}=  Catenate   python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"
    ${handle}=   Start Process   ${cmd}   shell=True
```

or simply

```
    ${handle}=   Start Process   python3 -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"   shell=True
```

Note that shell=True is sometimes necessary regardless of how the command string is passed, but is not not always the preferred solution - see the robot Process documentation referenced above.